# Creating own groovy library

Tags: groovy, jar

Do anyone have an idea whats the best way of creating an own library for groovy.

I have several methods which i just dont want copy and paste into all my groovy scripts.

The perfect solution would be to do it by an

```
import myownmethods
```

How to create the library myownmethods.jar?

Thanks for any answer and solution

Cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest method is to compile your groovy files with `groovyc` and then package them into a jar file with `jar`.  For example:

```
groovyc -d classes myclasses.groovy
jar cvf myclasses.jar -C classes .
```

I'd also consider looking at gradle.  To get started, you can use a `build.gradle` containing just:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
```

Then put your source files in a subdirectory called `src/main/groovy` and run `gradle jar`.  It will build your source files into a jar file in `build/libs`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! I tried it with the groovyc method, and i got my jar file in the end. I copied it into the lib dir of groovy main dir, but when i open the groovyConsole and type following:`import myclasses.* one() // method which just do println 1`
it doesnt seem to work... he cant find the method. What have i done wrong?

Comment: Stick the jar file in `.groovy/lib` in your home directory (`System.properties['user.home']`).  Or launch groovy with `groovyConsole -classpath myclasses.jar`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I copied into all possible folders but it didnt work. I then realized that you might need a class definition in the groovy which is compiled to class and packed into the jar. Works. This is not perfect but gives the needed workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the same process that you would for a Java library, i.e.

- Create a project for the code
- Configure your favorite build tool (Ant, Maven, etc.) to build a JAR for that project
- Put the JAR somewhere where other projects can find it. If you're using a tool like Ivy or Maven that does dependency management you'll likely want to deploy it to a repository. Otherwise, you can probably just put it somewhere in source control †
- Projects that depend on this library should either load it from the repository (if using dependency management), or have it copied into their `lib` directory (if not) †

† I know this sucks, but I can't remember how I used to manage dependencies without using a dependency management tool