# Can you upload groovy projects to the maven central repository?

Tags: maven, groovy

I have a class that does a lot of string manipulation that I originally wrote in Java. After playing around with Groovy, I think it would be easier to make this a seperate project that I write in Groovy and compile. I then want to upload it to the Maven repositoy and then include it back in the first project as a dependency in my POM file. This seems like it would be easier than trying to use the Bean Scripting Framework and keep everything in one project.

I know that you can compile Groovy code to a jar file (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170681/creating-own-groovy-library) SO thread). After reading the [Central Sync Requirements](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Central+Sync+Requirements) and the [Guide to uploading artifacts to the central repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html) I haven't seen anything that said that it wouldn't work. However, I'd like to avoid starting down this path just to find out that it was a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, there are already plenty of Groovy projects on Maven Central, like [http-builder](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder%22%20AND%20a%3a%22http-builder%22) and of course, [Groovy itself](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.codehaus.groovy%22%20AND%20a%3a%22groovy%22)!