# how to declare global function in jmeter and use anywhere in beanshell

Tags: jmeter

I'm facing with problem don't know how to create one Java function and call it to use anywhere because I don't want to write this function many times. Could anyone give me the best solution to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to proceed with Beanshell (however [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)) - take a look at [Beanshell configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#beanshell), there are properties like:

- `beanshell.init.file`
- `beanshell.sampler.init`
- etc.

where you can place the "common" code which can be reused in the Beanshell test elements.

---

For Groovy as of [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) there are no equivalent properties, however you should be able to [compile your Groovy code into a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170681/creating-own-groovy-library), put the file into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and invoke the functions defined in the .jar from any JSR223 Test element. Check out [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time) article for more details.

This approach can be applied to Beanshell as well if you still want to use it and find the properties not very convenient.