# How to declare common methods in JMeter for scripting to use in multiple threads

Tags: selenium, methods, jmeter

I am using selenium with JMeter and have written number of methods in groovy. But the challenge
I am facing is, in each sampler, I have to define all the created methods. Is there any way we can
call the methods created from a common place and use it anywhere in any sampler in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter-only solution would be placing your "common" functions into separate JSR223 Samplers living under [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and invoking them where required using [Module Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)

For "classic" way of re-using the code:

1. [Compile your Groovy "common" code into a .jar library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8170861/2897748)
2. Put the library somewhere in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar file with your common functions
4. Enjoy

More information: [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time)

Answer (score 0):

To create methods in a central place that you can re-use:

In a JSR223 sampler set to use groovy, create the reusable function, such as this one:

```
String logCommon() {
    String threadNumber = ctx.getThreadNum().toString();
    return "Thread #: " + threadNumber;
}
props.put('logging_common', this.&logCommon);
```

Then create a JSR223 Sampler again with groovy somewhere later and call the function:

```
String logCommon = props.get('logging_common')();
log.info(logCommon);
```

This pattern helps centralise your code.

Note, the samplers can be in different threadgroups because the function is stored as a property (using 'props'). If the function was stored a variable ('vars' instead), then both samplers would need to be in the same threadgroup.